# Facing Architecture issue with KonyUIContext in Xcode 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, temenos-quantum

I'm writing iOS FFI methods for Kony application. In that, I'm presenting a viewcontroller on kony form. For this i am using KonyUIContext. Below is the code for the same.

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard  =  [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navVC = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
[KonyUIContext onCurrentFormControllerPresentModalViewController:navVC animated:NO];
```

After building the application i am getting error saying below:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_KonyUIContext", referenced from:   objc-class-ref in
>   KonySupportClass.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

KonySupportClass is my class name. Please help me to get this issue resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the reported issue by updating Kony plugins.